# Подмена @ConfigurationProperties при тестировании Spring приложения

Tags: spring, kotlin, junit, properties

Я использую аннотацию `@ConfigurationProperties` для инициализации data классов свойствами из application.yml. Но, при тестировании, я не хочу братьи значения этих свойств из файлов типа *.yml или *.properties. Мне нужно, что бы в некоторых тестах соответствующие data классы заполнялись сгенерированными значениями, вместо значений из application.yml.

Я пытался объявлять для этого обычные бины, доступные только в тестах, но Spring ругается, когда не может исполнить заполнение свойств, которое предписывает `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Существует-ли способ как-то подавить или подменить действие данной аннотации для одного конкретного специфического теста?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

Для генерации экземпляров этих data классов с автоматическим заполнением их свойств значениями я успешно использую библиотеку mockito. Поэтому тут проблемы нету. Проблема именно в том, что бы заставить spring использовать эти *замоканные* экземпляры вместо тех, которые генерируются за счёт аннотации `@ConfigurationProperties`.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

Сейчас приведу пример, как могло бы выглядеть то, чего я хочу:

```kotlin
class MyPropertiesFactory: IPropertiesFactory {
    override fun getValue(name: String): String = /*Тут код, создающий значения свойств по некоторым правилам, необходимым для теста. */
}

@TestPropertySource(propertiesFactory = MyPropertiesFactory::class)
```

Естественно, что интерфейс `IPropertiesFactory` - это гипотетический интерфейс, выдуманный мною для данного примера.

Comment: Используете в тестах `@TestPropertySource ` ? Пример использования https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing-configurationproperties

Comment: Не совсем ясно. Если вы подменили бины, то при чем тут ConfigurationProperties? Я так понимаю проблема в том, чтоб спинг все еще создает бины, которые зависят от свойств, которые использует `ConfigurationProperties`, а вы их "подменили", но не совсем. Так?

Comment: @MrFylypenko, `@TestPropertySource` делает почти то, чего я хочу. Проблема в том, что он позволяет лишь изменить файл свойств, из которых будут браться проперти. Я хочу что бы `@TestPropertySource` позволил указать на фабрику, которая будет генерировать свойства программно, а не брать их из файла свойств. 


В обычной работе такое не нужно, а в тестах бывает.

Comment: @МихайлуцЮрий можно переопределять для конкретного теста нужные property `@TestPropertySource(properties = {"localization.strict-mode = true", "localization.strict = true"})`, а не изменять файл свойств. Если хотите менять на рандомное значение, то не понятно для чего это нужно, лучше дополните вопрос. [Так же есть @ConditionalOnProperty для переопределения конфигурации в зависимости от properties](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty) . Из вопроса не понимаю какой результат хотите получить, хочу увидеть пример теста.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, сейчас  дополню пример того, чего я хотел бы в вопросе.

Comment: @МихайлуцЮрий по идее `@SpyBean` с переопределением геттера у конфигурации должно хватить, можно обернуть как фабрику для тестового окружения. Так же можно попробовать объявлять конфигурацию [в методе, а не над классом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232480/6752984) с разделением профилей к примеру. На крайний случай вообще обновлять контест спринга.  Что нужно таким образом тестировать для меня загадка.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, спасибо. Я попробую использовать `@SpyBean`.